# scrollIntoView does not trigger mousewheel nor scroll event in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, events, event-handling

I use Angular and registered a `mousewheel` and `scroll` event. When I use `scrollIntoView` this event is not triggered. Is there any other event I miss?

```
  @HostListener('mousewheel', ['$event'])
  mousewheel(event: MouseEvent) {
    console.log("mousewheel");
  }

  @HostListener('scroll', ['$event'])
  scroll(event: MouseEvent) {
    console.log("scroll");
  }
```

And I use the function as this:

```
element.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'});
```

Does anyone know what I miss here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use **addEventListener** to add the scroll functionality. Also, don't forget to remove it in ngOnDestroy Here's an example:

```
export class WindowScrollDirective implements OnInit, OnDestroy{

 ngOnInit() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll, true); 
 }

 ngOnDestroy() {
     window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll, true);
 }

 handleScroll = (event): void => {
   //handle your scroll here
   
 };
}
```

**NOTE**: you can replace the window object by the element you want to use for scrolling.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try that. So I need to register both events? `mousewheel` and `scroll`?

Comment: You're welcome. If this helps you don't forget to accept this as the correct answer :). Thanks

Comment: @DanielStephens you don't need to use mousewheel anymore. Just add the scroll event to your element and you should be good.